# How to use interp2d on an array to create a periodic mesh?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have an array x and an array y containing the column and row indices of a function v defined on a mesh. I want to calculate the function on another mesh (say xnew and ynew), which is essentially the first mesh tiled over and over again, possibly with a coarser mesh spacing. This is an example of what I am trying to do, where the spacing is the same:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
N=10
a=np.arange(N)
b=np.arange(N)
Xax,Yax=np.meshgrid(a,b)
v=np.sin(Xax+Yax)
f=interpolate.interp2d(Xax,Yax,v)
xnew=np.mod(np.arange(100),N)
ynew=np.mod(np.arange(100),N)
vnew=f(xnew,ynew)
```

I get the following error on IPython

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-83ec5c3d24a5> in <module>()
----> 1 vnew=f(xnew,ynew)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.pyc in __call__(self,x,y,dx,dy)
    185         x = atleast_1d(x)
    186         y = atleast_1d(y)
--> 187         z = fitpack.bisplev(x, y, self.tck, dx, dy)
    188         z = atleast_2d(z)
    189         z = transpose(z)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.pyc in bisplev(x, y, tck, dx, dy)
    962     z,ier=_fitpack._bispev(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,x,y,dx,dy)
    963     if ier==10:
--> 964         raise ValueError("Invalid input data")
    965     if ier:
    966         raise TypeError("An error occurred")

ValueError: Invalid input data
```

I guess the problem is due to the fact that the second array is larger than the first one, since this works:

```
vnew=f(xnew[:N],ynew[:N])
```

One way to solve the problem would be to create the entire tiled array, but that would be a large array which I am trying to avoid. All the points in my example lie in the cell, any idea how to implement the interpolation?

Comment: I do not get an error from your code. Perhaps you should update to a newer version of scipy?

Comment: Hi @Julius, I don't get an error now either. I guess the problem is resolved in the new version!